# Kentico Xperience CMS - Cannot connect to SQL, "The thread was being aborted"

Tags: kentico

[image: The thread was being aborted.]

I've been working on creating reproducible development virtual machines for my team's work on Xperience CMS with the Hashicorp Vagrant tool. In this environment, the Xperience 13 administrative backend is encountering a runtime error upon startup, as can bee seen in the attached screenshot. I can confirm that the CMS connection string is correct because I have been able to successfully run an Xperience MVC Core site in the very same environment with the very same connection string. I have also used the exact same connection string to directly open a SQL connection using PowerShell in the exact same environment.

Things I have tried to diagnose the issue:

- I have tried increasing the execution timeout to the maximum allowed value. The runtime error still occurs, and long before the timeout's default value of 2400 seconds.
- I have tried attaching the Visual Studio debugger. The debugger reported "'CMS.DataEngine.ApplicationInitException' in CMS.DataEngine.dll" but no further details or stack trace.
- I have confirmed the correct firewall passthrough rules are in place.
- I have completely turned off Windows Firewall.

The environment is running on Hyper-V inside a Windows 10 host. The guest development environment has the following specs:

- Windows 11 Pro 21H2
- 16GB RAM
- 200GB Virtual Drive
- 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11800H @ 2.30GHz   2.30 GHz - 4 virtual processors
- SQL Server 2019
- All required IIS features enabled for XperienceCMS
- .NET Framework 4.8
- Kentico Xperience CMS 13 Hotfix 47

I'm running out of ideas to diagnose this problem.

Comment: Check the machines event log for more specific errors.  Most likely you'll find some error with asp.net or the app pool stopping due to errors. 

Confirm your app pool is also running as .net 4.8 and NOT in classic mode.  Lastly is is safe to assume the CMS code and the MVC code are on the same machine connecting to the same remote or local database?

Answer (score 0):

It was an NTFS folder permissions issue on `inetpub\wwwroot` that either wasn't being applied or wasn't being propagated down the hierarchy. IIS_IUSRS needed `Modify` permissions. Setting then resetting `Modify`, `Read`, and `Execute` permissions and propagating them down to subfolders and files solved the issue.